# Extract exact element from array by matching pattern in unix

Tags: bash, unix

```
myArray=('Prasanth' 'kumar' 'guru')
```

Is it possible to get element which ends with **"santh"** without iterating the `array(myArray)` with bash.

My expected output is to get **Prasanth** without iterating the above array, just by checking wildcard like (*'santh'*)and get the element.

Comment: By "unix" you mean "bash", right? The answer is probably "no". You can't apply a condition to select values from an array without iterating through the array.

Comment: You can't really do that in *any* language -- finding elements of an array that match a test necessarily requires iterating through the array, being an O(n) operation, unless it's indexed to allow that specific test to be performed more quickly. Some languages have sorted sets or dictionaries that let you do prefix searches quickly, but I've never seen one that would let you do a suffix search, unless it's a language organized around a datastore. (Languages that hide the iteration, sure; languages that *don't need to iterate*, not without preconfigured indexing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest:

```
printf '%s\n' "${myArray[@]}" | grep 'santh$'
```

Output:

```
Prasanth
```